# Loading images in the background for a table view

Tags: array, image, asynchronous, swift

I have `fetchData` method which fills my `imagesArray`:

```
func fetchData(){

    let imageQuery = PFUser.query()
    imageQuery?.whereKey("username", containedIn: namesArray)

    imageQuery!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            for object in objects! {
                print("\(object["username"] as! String)")

                self.imagesArray.append(object["image"] as! PFFile)
                if self.imagesArray.count == self.namesArray.count {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                    print("Names Order: \(self.namesArray)")
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("error: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

And I have `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` method which uses this array to fill the `UIImageView` instance:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! ChatsCell
    cell.nameLabel.text = namesArray[indexPath.row]

    if imagesArray.count == namesArray.count && self.imagesLoaded == false{
        imagesArray[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                cell.imageView?.image = image
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                self.imagesLoaded = true
            }
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

Actually I use if condition for waiting my array `imagesArray` to be filled by query of another method and I use variable `imagesLoaded` to prevent infinite call of `reloadData` method. How can I write this method without `if` statement?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Why do you want to remove your if condition, do you think it's inelegant or inefficient?

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan yes I think so. I think It can be cleaner :)

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason that `imagesArray` and `namesArray` have to be separated? If not, I probably will design a `struct` and join above two arrays to one since name and image can be fetched at the same time in `func fetchData()`.

For example, let's assume we have a `struct` like:

```
struct Person {
    var username: String
    var image: PFFile
}
```

Then we have a global mutable array:

```
var items = [Person]()
```

Inside the for-loop in `func fetchData()`, we can create a new person and append it each time once we have a name and an image.

```
let person = Person(username: "myName", image: "myImage")
self.items.append(person)
```

Therefore, in the `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {}`, we can get a person and associated username and image directly according to indexPath.row

```
let person = self.items[indexPath.row]
let username = person.username
let image = person.image
```

The benefits like this is that,

- Cell count is restricted by `self.items.count`; therefore, no
  worries to take care of indexPath.row beyond an array.
- Also username and image are always paired. It also helps to avoid
  concerning the order as imagesArray and namesArray are separated. No
  doubt, the condition `imagesArray.count == namesArray.count` can
  be removed as well.
- As to boolean `self.imagesLoaded` which is able to be removed. Owing to before remote data has been fetched, self.items.count is 0 and none cell will be rendered at that moment.

Comment: It's a nice answer. But note that the appropriate style for code terms is using `` `backticks` `` and not `**bold text**`